# jQuery .next selector not finding class

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery to select the next list element and clone the class `.slide-title` then append it to another class.

`$('li:visible').next('.slide-title').clone().appendTo('.feat_next');`

This is the HTML and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peter/JUYSF/3/) If I remove the selector from the `.next()` function it clones the next list element and appends it. So why isn't it finding the `.slide-title` class?

Thanks

```
<ul id="slider" style="position: relative;">
    <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 4; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="content_left">
            <p class="slide-date">July 2, 2012</p>
            <h2><a class="slide-title" href="#">3333333333</a></h2>asdfasfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfdasfdasfdasfd
            <p class="post-byline">by admin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img_right"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;">
        <div class="content_left">
            <p class="slide-date">April 1, 2013</p>
            <h2><a class="slide-title" href="#">asdfasdfasdf</a></h2>asdfasfasdfasdfasdf
            <p class="post-byline">by admin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img_right"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;">
        <div class="content_left">
            <p class="slide-date">April 2, 2013</p>
            <h2><a class="slide-title" href="#">223234234</a></h2>asdfasfdasfasfasfasdfasdf
            <p class="post-byline">by admin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img_right"><a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
        <div class="feat_next"><a href="#"></a></div>
        <div class="feat_prev"><a href="#"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will get the next sibling which must be an `li`. You can then use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to check an element's descendants.

```
$('li:visible').next('li').find('.slide-title').clone().appendTo('.feat_next');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/). `.next()` only finds the next sibling of the selected element. You would need to use `.find()` to retrieve what you are after.